# Java class extends from multiple classes

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragmentactivity, extends

I was having some problem when trying extend more than one class in Android development. So basically what I am trying to do is I got a navigation drawer:

```
customAdapter = new CustomExpandAdapter(this, listParent, listDataChild);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    // Navigation drawer with sub menu goes here
private void selectItem(int groupPosition, int position) {
    selectedPosition = position;
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerView);

    // Navigation item for profile
    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        switch (selectedPosition) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;      
    else if (groupPosition == 3) {
        switch (selectedPosition) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(ENeighbourhoodActivity.this, "Analyze Event",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }
    setTitle(mEventSelection[selectedPosition]);
}
```

And these codes are in my **MainActivity.java**. Then from my MainActivity, when I selected certain button, I will navigate to **Detail.java**. However, in my **Detail.java**, I am extending FragmentActivity because I am using tab inside **Detail.java**:

```
public class EventDetailMain extends FragmentActivity {
Context context = this;

ViewPager Tab;
EventDtlTabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;
}
```

And when I go to Detail.java, the navigation drawer is no longer there because I did not extend from the class. I wonder how should I extend from two class at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't extend from more than one class; you can, however, implement more than one interface. Java supports multiple inheritance of _behaviour_, not state.

Comment: So I should make my navigation drawer class as interface so that my Detail.java could extends from fragmentActivity and implements the interface?

Comment: @fge Can I assume that?

Comment: That is a possibility indeed, yes

Comment: @Denise just a hint: inheritance is evil. The less you use it the better and simpler your code.

Comment: @Foxinsocks inheritance _done badly_ is evil; but that's the same with everything

Comment: @Foxinsocks Other than using inheritance, do you have any other ideas how to perform it?

Answer (score 0):

In main activity take  Detail.java as a fragment and write your code.In this way the navigation drawer available to the your Detail.java also.

Comment: Would you mind to provide me some example to do fragment instead of intent?